# C++ linked lists using pointers - beginner question

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have been learning C++ for the last couple of months, and after going through an online course I have started doing some challenges with using raw pointers. I have successfully created class that can initiate and iterate through linked list, with lots of struggle I managed to create method that deletes its element(s), but I am struggling to write a method that would remove all the duplicates.

I have a method such as

```
void linked_list::remove_dups(){
    Node *p = first;
    Node *g = first;
    while(p!=NULL){
        int x = 0;
        g = new Node;
        g = first;
        Node *remove = first;
        while (g!=NULL){
            if(p->data == g->data){
                x++;
            }
            
            if(x>1){
                remove = new Node;
                remove = p;
                p = p->next;
                remove->next = p->next;
                delete remove;
                x--;
            }
            g = g->next;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

where Node is standard

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

first is private member

```
Node *first;
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong in this function and explain please? I initiated list with pointers that is
`int a[] = {3,5,5,7,65,5,65,65,4,4,15};`
and it removed most of the duplicates, but not all. If I add more though, I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Unrelated: `g = new Node;` followed by `g = first;` is what's called a memory leak. the first line dynamically allocated a `Node` and before it was used for anything or put anywhere safe, the pointer to this allocation was overwritten. Without a pointer to it, a dynamic allocation is next to impossible to find again and `delete`. Only use `new` when you absolutely have to, and in this case it doesn't look like you have to.

Comment: The best way I know of to troubleshoot linked lists is to draw pictures. Draw the list. Then step-by step draw what the list looks like as you perform an operation on it. While drawing make sure you never remove a link without still having a reference to the node it linked. You almost always will need that node accessible so you can relink it elsewhere  or `delete` it. Use the drawings as the basis for your code.

Comment: When it comes time to debug the code, follow your code exactly and see if you can redraw the same drawings. If you can't you'll find the bug pretty quickly and usually have a pretty good idea of what you needed to do instead.

Comment: Once you get the memory leaks taken care of, you could use a hashmap ```std::map<>```to insert node data, and if it appears more than once delete the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is:

```
            p = p->next;
            remove->next = p->next;
            delete remove;
```

You try to set `remove->next` to point to the new next element. But `remove` is going to be deleted. So the element before `remove` will still point to something deleted. So, after the delete, you'll have a broken list that contains pointer to deleted elements. Next loop iteration, it will break.

Below is the code I edited as I went. Please note that

```
            remove = new Node;
            remove = p;
```

is not only useless, it leaks memory. You can directly do `remove = p;`

Just draft code as I went. Not fixed. Proper would be keeping a `prev` pointer or something.

```
void linked_list::remove_dups()
{
    Node *p = first;
    Node *g = first;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        // int x = 0; remove this
        // g = new Node; remove this
        g = first;
    
        Node *remove = first;
        while (g != NULL)
        {
            if(p->data == g->data) // test directly, no x
            {
                // remove = new Node; remove this
                remove = p;
                p = p->next;
                // remove->next = p->next; You are going to delete this, no point modifying it
                delete remove;
            }
            g = g->next;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: I'd expect at least one pointer -to-pointer or an update to `first` to handle cases where the first node is removed. Then again, maybe not. If the first element is a duplicate something really really strange is going on. Ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote for my custom doubly-linked list that will remove duplicates. Not necessarily the most efficient but it gets the job done.

```
void unique()
    {
      std::map<int, int> hash;
      Node<T>* temp = this->head;
      while(temp)
      {
        hash[temp->data]++;
        if(hash[temp->data] > 1)
        {
          Node<T>* next = temp->next;
          Node<T>* prev = temp->prev;
          delete temp;
          temp = nullptr;
          if(!next)
          {          
            temp = prev;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            hash[temp->data]--;
            break;
          }
          next->prev = prev;
          prev->next = next;
          temp = next;
          hash[temp->data]--;
        }
        else
        {
          temp = temp->next;
        }
      }
    }
```